# some color not easily visible in vim syntax highlight

Tags: vim

I am using the solarized plugin and some text like the R builtin function and nerdtree directory are displayed in a color that is not easily visible, is there a way to fix this?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with tmux 2, the terminal setting is "use colors from system theme", and built in color palette "solarized"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would comment if I could, but do you use `set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"` in your `.tmux.conf`?

Comment: E558: Terminal entry not found in terminfo
'tmux-256color' not known. Available builtin terminals are:
    builtin_amiga
    builtin_beos-ansi
    builtin_ansi
    builtin_pcansi
    builtin_win32
    builtin_vt320
    builtin_vt52
    builtin_xterm
    builtin_iris-ansi
    builtin_debug
    builtin_dumb
defaulting to 'ansi'

Comment: my initial setting is set -g default-terminal "screen-256color" which will not generate any error

Comment: `screen-256color` should be fine too

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that I forgot to change the terminal profile to the new profile I created, the default is unnamed which did not use a solarized scheme. Problems solved by choosing the new profile as the terminal profile. In ubuntu 16.04 this is confusing.